# Seeking midi processor iOS app for external keyboard that runs in background (does not have to own screen on iPad)

Tags: midi, keyboard

I have a portable keyboard/piano ([FVEREY 88 Key Foldable Digital Piano Keyboard](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B08TTKGT5Z/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) which I connect to my iPad using a usb cable and handy adapter (usb camera adapter), and currently if I run GarageBand and Perfect Piano on my iPad I can get a midi-processed signal to earbuds or speaker from the iPad (cable only, bluetooth delay is bad) that is much much better than the keyboard's native sound.

However, Perfect Piano only works as the active app, so I can't read music on the iPad.
Does anyone know of an app that will take a keyboard input and make it sound better while **running in the background** so I can also read music on the iPad? Doesn't have to be free, just functional. I'm looking for something fairly simple, I don't do much other than use the keyboard for piano practice while traveling, and I just want better sound quality.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid recommendations for apps or other resources isn't among the [topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).